# Android application lifecycle when bound to a remote service

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle

I have an android application that binds itself to a remote service once the application starts. The remote service provides an abstraction to a bluetooth video camera so we can send commands and receive events from it easily. The binding happens from the `Application` itself as opposed to an `Activity`. It is important to me that as long as the camera connection to bluetooth is active that my application stay running so I can receive events from the remote service. The main reason is that I need to know if it's recording or not and if so I need to periodically send it GPS coordinates.

Will my application have a better chance of not being killed if I use a service within my own application to manage that? Or is my application safe from being killed since it is still bound to the remote service? Of course, I understand that the android system will kill my app if memory requirements require it to but will it ever kill my app just because it's been sitting for awhile not doing much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application's process should only be removed if memory is low, but you will raise the perceived  importance of your process if you use a service rather than an empty process or a background activity. You can also use startForeground() to make it less likely that Android will stop your service.

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle:

> ### Process Lifecycle
>
> The Android system attempts to keep application process around for as
> long as possible, but eventually will need to remove old processes
> when memory runs low. As described in Activity Lifecycle, the decision
> about which process to remove is intimately tied to the state of the
> user's interaction with it. In general, there are four states a
> process can be in based on the activities running in it, listed here
> in order of importance. The system will kill less important processes
> (the last ones) before it resorts to killing more important processes
> (the first ones).
>
> 1. The **foreground** activity (the activity at the top of the screen that the user is currently interacting with) is considered the most
>    important. Its process will only be killed as a last resort, if it
>    uses more memory than is available on the device. Generally at this
>    point the device has reached a memory paging state, so this is
>    required in order to keep the user interface responsive.
> 2. A **visible** activity (an activity that is visible to the user but not in the foreground, such as one sitting behind a foreground
>    dialog) is considered extremely important and will not be killed
>    unless that is required to keep the foreground activity running.
> 3. A **background** activity (an activity that is not visible to the user and has been paused) is no longer critical, so the system may
>    safely kill its process to reclaim memory for other foreground or
>    visible processes. If its process needs to be killed, when the user
>    navigates back to the activity (making it visible on the screen
>    again), its onCreate(Bundle) method will be called with the
>    savedInstanceState it had previously supplied in
>    onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) so that it can restart itself in the same
>    state as the user last left it.
> 4. An **empty process** is one hosting no activities or other application components (such as Service or BroadcastReceiver classes).
>    These are killed very quickly by the system as memory becomes low. For
>    this reason, any background operation you do outside of an activity
>    must be executed in the context of an activity BroadcastReceiver or
>    Service to ensure that the system knows it needs to keep your process
>    around.
>
> Sometimes an Activity may need to do a long-running operation that
> exists independently of the activity lifecycle itself. An example may
> be a camera application that allows you to upload a picture to a web
> site. The upload may take a long time, and the application should
> allow the user to leave the application will it is executing. To
> accomplish this, your Activity should start a Service in which the
> upload takes place. This allows the system to properly prioritize your
> process (considering it to be more important than other non-visible
> applications) for the duration of the upload, independent of whether
> the original activity is paused, stopped, or finished.

Comment: Good answer! I've actually switched my application a few months ago to use a Service with startForeground which seems to have helped nicely.